# Magento how to add product to cart programmatically based on customer id

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I am trying to add an item to cart programmatically based on customer id, am trying this below code

```
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(403);
    $customerId = '39';         
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customerId);
    $quote->addProduct($product, 1);
    $quote->setIsActive(1);
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

But here the customer id not exist in the Collection, then am't able to add the product to cart

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customerId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the user's current quote this way:

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
```

It will retrieve the current "cart" of said customer (connected or not). You'll then be able to manipulate it to add a product and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding product

```
 require_once '../app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();
 umask(0);

 $customerID = 1615;
 $product_id = 598;
 $product_qty = 3;

// Load quote by Customer
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
         ->loadByCustomer($customerID);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                     ->load($product_id);

// Add Product to Quote
$quote->addProduct($product,$product_qty);

try {
    // Calculate the new Cart total and Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    $cart = array(
    'status'=> True,
    'message'=> 'Product is added to cart successfully'
    );
    echo json_encode($cart);

} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    $error = array(
    'status' => False,
    'message'=> $this->_error($e->getMessage(),Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR)
    );
   echo json_encode($error); 
}
```